# Android: Generate integrated Zxing Based Streaming QR code

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-studio, zxing

I am supposed to convert an selected Image to Base64. Then split the Base64 string to equal sized arrays and use that string to generate multiple QR codes.

I've successfully managed to break down the string to equal sized arrays and generate 1 QR code for for the 1st array (Base64Parts[0]) using the following

```js
QRCodeWriter writer = new QRCodeWriter();
                try {
                    BitMatrix bitMatrix = writer.encode(Base64Parts[0], BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 512, 512);
                    int width = bitMatrix.getWidth();
                    int height = bitMatrix.getHeight();
                    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
                    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                            bmp.setPixel(x, y, bitMatrix.get(x, y) ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE);
                        }
                    }
                    ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_holder)).setImageBitmap(bmp);

                } catch (WriterException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

The core-3.2.1.jar file was provided by Zxing was downloaded from the Maven Repository and added to the libs directory.

From this point onwards what must be done to generate QR codes for each string arrays generated from the Image? Should a 'for' loop be used or is there any other method?
And what method should the QR codes be displayed? As a timed image in a ImageView? A video or a GIF?
And using the code given above can the Error Correction Level of the QR code generated be altered?

Thank You

Comment: I think you should ask ZXing author about your questions? https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/issues

Comment: Do you think that a 'for' condition can be used so that I can convert each strings to separate QR codes?